# How Do I Know If the Report is in Page 1 using RDLC?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, reportviewer, rdlc

If the page is equal to 1, I want to display the value "T O T A L" and if not the value "T O T A L  F O R W A R D E D" should display instead.

Since the variable `Globals!PageNumber` cannot be called outside Header and Footer, is there any other method?

The formula is supposed to be easy but does not work. It should be like this:

```
=iif(Globals!PageNumber > 1, "T O T A L  F O R W A R D E D", "T O T A L")
```

Comment: Are you sure you can access the variable ? is `iif(2>1, "T O T A L F O R W A R D E D", "T O T A L")` working?

Comment: this is an interesting link regarding this problem (see raymond-lee's posts): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/243e6b82-70f5-4051-8b3f-4110f931591f/using-global-variables-page-numbers-in-the-report-body?forum=sqlreportingservices